# Deserializing constructor doesn't read data correctly

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am trying to deserialize an object that does not have a default constructor. I've seen that you can do this by passing an archive to a constructor. However, when I do this it does not seem to read the data correctly? Here is an example - `Works()` outputs "1 2" as it should (using a default constructor and the operator>>), but `DoesntWork()` outputs "0 0". I've stepped through and everything seems to be getting called appropriately. Can anyone explain the difference between these two functions?

```
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

class Point
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mX;
        archive & mY;
    }

public:
    template<class TArchive>
    Point(TArchive& archive)
    {
        serialize(archive, 0);
    }

    Point(){} // Only provided to test Works()

    Point(const float x, const float y) : mX(x), mY(y) { }

    float mX = 4;
    float mY = 5;
};

void Works()
{
    std::cout << "Works():" << std::endl;
    Point p(1,2);

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.archive");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << p;
    outputStream.close();

    // read from a text archive
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.archive");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    Point pointRead;
    inputArchive >> pointRead;

    std::cout << pointRead.mX << " " << pointRead.mY << std::endl;
}

void DoesntWork()
{
    std::cout << "DoesntWork():" << std::endl;
    Point p(1,2);

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.archive");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << p;
    outputStream.close();

    std::ifstream inputStream("test.archive");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    Point pointRead(inputArchive);

    std::cout << pointRead.mX << " " << pointRead.mY << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Works(); // Output "1 2"
    DoesntWork(); // Output "0 0"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that constructor _serialising_ rather than _deserialising_? How is `serialize(archive, 0)` supposed to deserialise?

Comment: @PreferenceBean serializing or deserializing depends on how TArchive defines operator &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `serialize` methods directly: `operator >>` for an archive does *way* more than just calling `serialize`; depending on the type of archive it first needs to load a preamble etc. You can verify this by stepping through with the debugger, or by checking what's inside test.archive, it is something like

```
22 serialization::archive 12 0 0 1.000000000e+000 2.000000000e+000
```

so right after constructing a `text_iarchive` the first two calls to `operator &` will happen to see those 2 `0`'s in there instead of the actual data.

Your constructor should be:

```
template<class TArchive>
Point(TArchive& archive)
{
  archive >> *this;
}
```

**Edit** here's an example of how to use SFINAE to make sure the copy constructor can still be invoked

```
Point( const Point& rh ) :
  mX( rh.mX ),
  mY( rh.mY )
{
}

template<class TArchive>
Point( TArchive& archive,
       std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same< TArchive, Point >::value >* = nullptr )
{
  archive >> *this;
}
```

Comment: I did notice those extra 0's but I assumed they were some kind of header. I expected the header to be automatically parsed since it was automatically written, but now I understand the difference - thanks!

Comment: If I already have a templated constructor, typically I would make a named static "constructor", but in this case I need access to the `this` pointer. Suggestions for best practice in this case?

Comment: I can't just name the other constructor instead, because a copy constructor, for example, must be a specific signature.

Comment: That's `Point( TArchive& archive,
       typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same< TArchive, Point >::value >::type* = nullptr )` for those of us behind the front lines :)

Comment: If you also have `template <typename T>
    Test(const std::vector<T>& v)`, the deserializing constructor may match before this one. It seems like instead of `!is_same<TArchive, Point>` it would be better to do something like `is_base_of<BoostArchive, TArchive>` to make it explicitly only for handling the case when an archive is passed. That is, now you are just preventing colliding with the copy constructor, but not other things. Do you know the right base boost class to check? The hierarchy isn't clear to a non-deity :)

Comment: Would indeed be better to match the intent as close as possible; An archive inherits multiple classes, but something like `std::is_base_of< boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive, TArchive >::value` should be fine

Comment: Care to try your luck on a natural follow up :) ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732363/deserializing-stl-container-of-type-with-no-default-constructor

Comment: Here is another example of the deserializing constructors not doing what I would expect - any thoughts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222439/deserializing-constructor-hierarchy/36223411?noredirect=1#comment60081089_36223411