# Deserializing constructor hierarchy

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

(This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722135/deserializing-construtor-doesnt-read-data-correctly), but this time I am calling the `Parent` deserializing constructor in the `Child` initialization list).

In a case where a `Child` adds no new data to be serialized, the `Parent` does not have a default constructor, I want to be able to serialize the `Parent` object directly as well as the `Child`, and neither the child nor the parent have default constructors, it seems like we should use the following pattern, where the child deserializing constructor initializes the parent (also using its deserializing constructor) in the initialization list:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class Parent
{
public:
    double mParentData;

    Parent(const double data) : mParentData(data) {}

    template<typename TArchive>
    Parent(TArchive& archive)
    {
        archive >> *this;
    }

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mParentData;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:

    Child(const double data) : Parent(data) {}

    template<typename TArchive>
    Child(TArchive& archive) : Parent(archive)
    {
        // Do nothing, as the only data to read is in Parent
    }

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // Let the parent do its serialization
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<Parent>(*this);

        // Nothing else to do, as the only data to read/write is in Parent
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child child(1.2);

    {
        std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);

        outputArchive << child;
        outputStream.close();
    }

    {
        std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
        Child childRead(inputArchive);

        std::cout << "childRead:" << std::endl
                  << childRead.mParentData << std::endl; // Outputs 0 (expected 1.2)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So the call chain should (and does) look like:

**Output:**

- Child::serialize()
- Parent::serialize()

**Input:**

- Child(archive)
- Parent(archive)
- Parent::serialize()

However, the `mParentData` ends up as `0` in `childRead`, when I would expect it to be `1.2`.

Can anyone spot the error?

----------- EDIT -----------

As pointed out by @stijn , in the case where the child has no additional data to serialize, we can simply remove the `serialize()` function from `Child` entirely, like this:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class Parent
{
public:
    double mParentData;

    Parent(const double data) : mParentData(data) {}

    template<typename TArchive>
    Parent(TArchive& archive)
    {
        archive >> *this;
    }

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mParentData;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:

    Child(const double data) : Parent(data) {}

    template<typename TArchive>
    Child(TArchive& archive) : Parent(archive)
    {
        // Do nothing, as the only data to read is in Parent
    }

};

int main()
{
    Child child(1.2);

    {
        std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);

        outputArchive << child;
        outputStream.close();
    }

    {
        std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
        Child childRead(inputArchive);

        std::cout << "childRead:" << std::endl
                  << childRead.mParentData << std::endl; // Outputs 0 (expected 1.2)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, in the case when both the child and parent have data to serialize, and they both do not have a default constructor, the pattern seems like it would need to be something like the following, but not quite. In the `Child` deserializing constructor, we are calling both the `Parent` deserializing constructor, but also the `Child::serialize()` function, which calls the `Parent::serialize()` function, so effectively the `Parent` would try to deserialize twice. This incorrect behavior is demonstrated here:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class Parent
{
public:
    double mParentData;

    Parent(const double data) : mParentData(data) {}

    template<typename TArchive>
    Parent(TArchive& archive)
    {
        archive >> *this;
    }

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mParentData;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:

    double mChildData;

    Child(const double parentData, const double childData) : Parent(parentData), mChildData(childData) {}

    template<typename TArchive>
    Child(TArchive& archive) : Parent(archive)
    {
        archive >> *this;
    }

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // Let the parent do its serialization
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<Parent>(*this);

        // Do the child serialization
        archive & mChildData;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child child(1.2, 3.4);

    {
        std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);

        outputArchive << child;
        outputStream.close();
    }

    {
        std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
        Child childRead(inputArchive);

        std::cout << "childRead:" << std::endl
                  << childRead.mParentData << std::endl  // Outputs 0.2 (expected 1.2)
                  << childRead.mChildData << std::endl; // Outputs 3.4 correctly
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It seems like somehow we need to call a different version of `Child::serialize()` from the `Child` deserializing constructor? Or set a flag to not explicitly deserialize `Parent` from `Child::serialize()` if it is called from the `Child` deserializing constructor?

If we change the `Child::serialize()` to the following, I get a segfault:

```
template<class TArchive>
void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
{
    // Let the parent do its serialization
    Parent::serialize(archive, version);

    // Do the child serialization
    archive & mChildData;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but if you just remove the `serialize()` function in Child it will work as expected, no? The function is not needed anyway since there's nothing to serialize, as you say yourself in the comments, and even if it were I don't think forwarding calls to the parent class has to be done with `&` but by calling `serialize`, i.e. you have to call call Parent::serialize or boost::serialization::serialize(archive,boost::serialization::base_object<Parent>(*this),version); which wll end up calling Parent::serialize anyway

Comment: You're exactly right @stijn, it works fine to remove the `Child::serialize()` entirely when the parent is the only one that has data to serialize. I added an example case to the question where the child DOES have additional data to serialize. I tried calling `Parent::serialize(archive, version)` from `Child::serialize()`, but it segfaults. (and the same with `boost::serialization::serialize(archive, boost::serialization::base_object<Parent>(*this),version);`)

Comment: In that case I think Lukas' answer is the way to go, or else pointers/registering types, and the docs seem to confirm that

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you don't need to forward the deserialization to the parent. 
Changing your code to

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class Parent
{
public:
  double mParentData;

  Parent(const double data) : mParentData(data) {}

  template<typename TArchive>
  Parent(TArchive& archive, bool deserialize = false)
  {
    if (!deserialize)
      archive >> *this;
  }

  template<class TArchive>
  void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
  {
    archive & mParentData;
  }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:

  Child(const double data) : Parent(data) {}

  template<typename TArchive>
  Child(TArchive& archive) : Parent(archive, true)
  {
    archive >> *this;
  }

  template<class TArchive>
  void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
  {
    // Let the parent do its serialization
    archive & boost::serialization::base_object<Parent>(*this);

    // Nothing else to do, as the only data to read/write is in Parent
  }
};

int main()
{
  {
    Child child(1.2);
    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);

    outputArchive << child;
    outputStream.close();
  }

  {
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    Child childRead(inputArchive);


    std::cout << "childRead:" << std::endl
      << childRead.mParentData << std::endl; // Outputs 0 (expected 1.2)
  }

  return 0;
}
```

works for me.

Comment: Yep, forgot to explicitly mention that I don't have and don't want default constructors. That is the whole reason to use deserializing constructors at all vs just `archive >> object;`

Comment: I see. Using my approach, what about an empty deserialization constructor in the `Parent` class and keep the deserialization logic in the `Child` class. Like, `template<typename TArchive>
  Child(TArchive& archive) : Parent(archive)
  {
    archive >> *this;
  }` . Using this approach it is possible to remove the default ctors. See edited post.

Comment: That would likely work for `Child`, but then I can't serialize and deserialize the `Parent` directly. (e.g. `Parent parent(1.2); outArchive << parent; Parent readParent(inArchive);`)

Comment: That's correct. There might be a better solution for this, but in this case I would probably add a default parameter to the deserializing ctor of `Parent`. Such as that derived class can tell the parent class not to deserialize itself. `Parent(TArchive& archive, bool deserialize = false)`

Comment: Good idea, that's not a terrible workaround. But it does still seem like we are doing something incorrectly (i.e. WHY doesn't this work as I'm expecting?)

Comment: My best guess would be that by doing `archive >> *this;` in the parent class you loose/slice the information of the polymorphic type. Perhaps another solution would be to use pointers, see [http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers)

Comment: Everything gets way more complicated (you have to register types, etc.) when using pointers with the Boost serialization stuff, so I'd like to avoid doing that where possible. My concern is the case where child and parent both have data to deserialize - there would need to be code duplication that could accidentally get out of sync (the parent `serialize()` would need to contain exactly the same code in the same order as the beginning of the child `serialize()`. Has anyone else come across this problem?

Comment: You can avoid using pointers ***where possible***. Clearly this is not such a case. The documentation makes this clear.

Comment: @LukasBernreiter The flag would actually be `Parent(TArchive& archive, bool deserialize = true)
  {
    if (deserialize)
      archive >> *this;` and then `Child(archive)` would call ` : Parent(archive, false)`, right? I'm not sure this helps the case when the `Child` has extra data though?

Comment: Yes the idea is that the flag is just used as a workaround to be able to work with the parent alone as well. an additional field and a serialize method body like this `archive & boost::serialization::base_object<Parent>(*this); archive & m_child_data;` in the child should also just work fine.