# Deserializing STL container of type with no default constructor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I've recently learned the pattern of the deserializing constructor ([Deserializing constructor doesn't read data correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722135/deserializing-construtor-doesnt-read-data-correctly)) to use serialization with types that do not have default constructors. Now I'm trying to serialize an STL container of these objects, as in the example below:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class Point
{
public:
    Point(double x) : mX(x) {}

    template<class TArchive>
    Point(TArchive& archive)
    {
        archive >> *this;
    }

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mX;
    }

    double mX;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> pointVector;
    pointVector.push_back(Point(1));
    pointVector.push_back(Point(2));

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);

    outputArchive << pointVector;
    outputStream.close();

    std::vector<Point> readPointVector;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive >> readPointVector; // Compiler error - no matching function call to Point::Point()

    return 0;
}
```

It seems clear that this shouldn't work, but how would I tell the archive that it needs to use the deserializing constructor to construct the objects that it reads before adding them to the container?

---------- EDIT ----------

After implementing the suggestion in the only answer, this code compiles fine, but doesn't seem to deserialize correctly. The `readPointVector` only has size 1 but it should have size 2 (and the data is not correct in the one object that it does contain):

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class Point
{
public:
    Point(double x) : mX(x) {}

    template<class TArchive>
    Point(TArchive& archive)
    {
        archive >> *this;
    }

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mX;
    }

    double mX;
};

template <typename Archive>
Archive& operator >> (Archive& archive, std::vector<Point>& points)
{
    points.emplace_back(archive);
    return archive;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> pointVector;
    pointVector.push_back(Point(5.6));
    pointVector.push_back(Point(7.8));

    std::cout << pointVector.size() << std::endl; // outputs 2

    {
        std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);

        outputArchive << pointVector;
        outputStream.close();
    }

    std::vector<Point> readPointVector;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive >> readPointVector;

    std::cout << readPointVector.size() << std::endl; // outputs 1 (and readPointVector[0].mX is 2, but should be 7.8)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So this is just impossible? What is one supposed to do in this case?

Comment: Make sure that the type have a default constructor?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, `std::vector` **never** worked this way, it doesn't require elements to be default constructable. There is only one call for constructor, it is either move or copy.

Comment: also see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors maybe ?

Comment: @stijn That is for pointer types. I've been told not to use that when not using pointers (first comment by SergeyA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703958/disallow-serializing-an-object-directly-not-through-a-pointer-if-it-doesnt-ha)

Answer (score 2):

You may specialize for vector of Points:

```
template <typename Archive>
Archive& operator >> (Archive& archive, std::vector<Point>& points)
{
    points.emplace_back(archive);
    return archive;
}
```

Comment: Even better - use `emplace`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I guess I got too excited that it compiled and accepted the answer. It doesn't seem to do the right thing (see new demo in the EDIT in the question)?